# SIGABRT when cvReleaseImage

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-10.10

I think I'm confusing with pointers...

```
Vision vis;
    IplImage* imgB0=cvCreateImage(img_sz, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);
    IplImage* imgB1=cvCreateImage(img_sz, IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1);
    //Get next frame
    vis->getFrame();
    imgB0=vis->image;
    usleep(3);
    vis->getFrame();
    imgB1=vis->image;
    cvAddWeighted(imgB0, 1./(float)2., imgB1,1./(float)2.,0,imgB1);
    cvReleaseImage(&imgB0); //<-SIGABRT
    ...
```

Vision.h:

```
 class Vision
    {
    public:
        IplImage* image;
...
```

Vision.cpp:

```
void Vision::getFrame()
    {
        image = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: `Vision vis;` . `vis` is a stack allocated object and `.` operator needs to be used to access it's members. I amn't sure how you are using `->` operator on it to access it's members and getting a run time error. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Did class vision has overloaded operator->() ?

Comment: Vision::Vision()
{
 image = 0;
 capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(1);

Answer (score 3):

FRom [HighGUI Reference Manual](http://opencv.jp/opencv-1.0.0_org/docs/ref/opencvref_highgui.htm#decl_cvQueryFrame):

> The returned image should not be released or modified by user.

You're also leaking the two `cvImage`s you create.

Comment: hmm.. what's this.. "reference manual"? Not familiar with the term. This is Stack Overflow; we don't need no stinking documentation here!

Comment: So, i can't release imgB0 and imgB1? :(

Comment: @EnneKappa: Not the ones from `cvQueryFrame`. You might want something like `void Vision::getFrame() { image = cvCloneImage( cvQueryFrame(capture) ); }`